# Xilinx equivalent for Lattice's Input DDR generic mode in X2 gearing primitive

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog, xilinx, lattice

I used to work with Lattice FPGA (Lattice ECP3) and I used to have this primitive: IDDRX2D1
[image]

the block internal circuit:
[image]

I can't find an equivalent for this kind of input DDR in Xilinx Series 7 libraries,
the closest thing I found is this:
[image]
which is similar except that it's not 2x gearing, I need 4 outputs like the primitive from Lattice.
Any ideas if such a thing exists in Xilinx primitives?

Comment: Isn't this a question for the Xilinx support forums instead of here?

Comment: May be ISERDES ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISERDES is what you are looking for. 7-series libraries guide will give information about the instantiation of the ISERDES. But UG471 - 7 Series FPGAs SelectIO Resources User Guide will give more information on ISERDES. (You might find some other interesting components).

[image]